# Find command Permission denied

Tags: linux, find, debian

The command I entered:
sudo find /home/user/Series/ -iname sample -exec rm {} \;
What I got in return:
find: `/home/user/Series/': Permission denied

I tried to delete every file in this folder with the name sample, since sometimes movies contain sample files for instance, movename.1080p.etc.sample.mkv and I wanted to delete those files.. Unfortunately that wasn't the result :P Anyone any idea's :)?

Note: I also set this up as a cronjob as the following:

35 09 * * * /usr/bin/find /home/user/Series/ -iname sample -exec rm {} \;

Would that work?

Running: Wheezy, Debian

Kind regards,
Jorricks

Comment: Note: I tried CHMod 777 but it seems that only made it worse since before I got the error message:

/home/user/Series/Greys/Season 2/ permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a regular expression for "sample".  Change the command to

```
/usr/bin/find /home/user/Series/ -iname "*sample*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
How do I include removal of folders?

Comment: If you just want to remove folders, you will have to specify `-type d` and use `-r` option with `rm` (in case they are not empty).

Answer (score 1):

If you have files with filenames like "movename.1080p.etc.sample.mkv", you need to modify your find command to have a glob expression.  So try:

```
find /home/user/Series/ -iname '*sample*' -exec rm {} \;
```

The reason for your error is that the find doesn't find any files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, How do I include removal of folders?

Comment: The "rm" command has a "-r" option for "recursive remove".  For example "rm -r alpha", will remove the directory "alpha" and all its files and directories.

Just be sure that's what you want!

Answer (score 1):

If you are running command line, you probably need to switch to the sudo user.

Note that sudo is used twice, once on the find command, and once on the remove command.

```
sudo find /home/user/Series/ -iname sample -print0 | sudo xargs -0 rm -r
```

Mike